# Delphi - W1048 Unsafe typecast of 'string' to 'TFormatSettings'

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm porting an old project to Delphi XE and I receive this warning on the code bellow.

```
function RemoveThousandSeperator(Text: String) : String;
Var P : Integer;
begin
  if length(Text) > 3 then begin
    p := Pos(FormatSettings.ThousandSeparator,Text);
   while p >0 do begin
      Delete(Text,p,1);
      p := Pos(FormatSettings.ThousandSeparator,Text);
    end;
  end;
  result := Text;
end;
```

even FormatSettings.ThousandSeparator is of type char.

LE: I am asking if someone can tell me why this warning occurs. The code is old and it will be remade.

LE2 : In order to get this warning all the warnings needs to be set to true in the Delphi Compiler-Hints & Warnings

LE3: If someone needs it - {$WARN UNSAFE_CAST OFF} makes the warning go off.

LE4: a screenshot of the warning for those who believe that the warning is hard to believe

[image]

Comment: You should post the complete function, the fragment you provided is not enough.

Comment: I don't understand the -1. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: I just checked in XE2 and this code doesn't generate a warning.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff - I put the entire routine. anyway, the warning is not related to entire routine.

Comment: Looks like XE-specific. XE2 compiles that without a warning just fine. P.S. `StringReplace` sounds like a shorter code.

Comment: @KromStern - I will remake the code :) What I wanted is to understand why the warning occur.

Comment: why arent you using  StringReplace

Comment: The code you posted does not generate warnings in Delphi XE

Comment: @Serg - this is what I'm looking at now...Same routine in a new package/application does not generates this warning...

Comment: Delphi compiler directives may (or may not) influence this.  In classic configuration it was (AFAIR) `Ctrl+O,O` to insert them all into sources. But i may be wrong today

Comment: @RBA even if u wanted to implement this yourself- you'd obviously better do straight char by char copying into new pre-allocated string skipping some chars, rather than do quadratic n-times-copy-n-proportial-tail way like this.

Comment: @Arioch'The - I agree with you. I have said that I got this code, it isn't mine. I will re-make it. What I want is to understand why this is a warning.

Comment: That warning is hard to believe. You are not typecasting string to TFormatSettings. It's not even possible so if you tried it would be an error not a warning.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - please take a look at the image.

Comment: I remain incredulous. Looks like a compiler bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The origin of the warning is declaration of `FormatSettings` variable in `SysUtils.pas`:

```
var
  // Note: Using the global FormatSettings variable corresponds to using the
  // individual global formatting variables and is not thread-safe.
  FormatSettings: TFormatSettings absolute CurrencyString;
```

which casts string (`CurrencyString`) to record (`TFormatSettings`).

So the problem that generates the warning is in `SysUtils.pas`, not in the code you posted,
though the warning is generated in your code.

---

Here is a test case (Delphi XE):

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$WARN UNSAFE_CAST ON}

type
  TTest = record
    FS: string;
  end;

var
  Str: string;
  Test: TTest absolute Str;

begin
  Str:= 'abc';
  Writeln(Test.FS);   //  W1048 Unsafe typecast of 'string' to 'TTest'
end.
```

Comment: There's no way that should lead to this compiler warning. It has to be compiler bug.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - the issue is easily reproducible in Delphi XE without `SysUtils.pas`. Delphi XE is my last Delphi, you can test the latest versions. The warning is logical but appears in the wrong place.

Comment: I guess the project compiles SysUtils.pas (Debug DCUs?) and that causes the warning to be generated.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff - no, nothing like that is needed.

Comment: @serg I don't agree. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - `absolute` is just a postponed typecast. I don't understand what exactly you don't agree.

Comment: So this is an expected warning?  My nearly-duplicate question asked if you can fix it. My guess is no you can't, just do the `{$WARN UNSAFE_CAST OFF}`